# Access files from another project same solution asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, filepath

I have solution "solution" and two projects:

- **solution.WebUI** (here user uploads file to some folder like "~/uploads"
- **solution.WebApi** (here I must access user files)

In web api project I access files like this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetPdfPage()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responce =  new HttpResponseMessage();
        responce.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/somefile.pdf"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        responce.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        return responce;
    }
```

How must I modify path to file?

Answer (score 1):

I think Shared folder is a better solution
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324267

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar kind of problem where I need to access the Upload folder of another project(main) from the BLL project under same solution.
For that I have used absolute path(not hardcoded) for the Upload folder. I think the code below should also work for you.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetPdfPage()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responce =  new HttpResponseMessage();
        string basePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        responce.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(basePath +"somefile.pdf"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        responce.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        return responce;
    }
```